# Horizontal ul li navigation bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, adaptive-ui

I have ul li navigation with bootsrap , where li has fixed width, and I have got a lot of li, and I want to show all li elements of menu on mobile (I dont know how)

Problem : I want to show all menu in `horizontal` way on mobile, but it's going `vertical`, and how to put all elements to the small screen

https://jsfiddle.net/fvove846/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fvove846/1/

Answer (score 0):

You forget the `display:inline` in your css,

try this code

```
.table_ul_nav{
    display: block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: inline;
}
.table_ul_nav>li{
    width: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: but on mobile my menu will look like sh**, how to avoid this

Comment: on mobile it's gonna be vertical with your example, but how to make it horizonatal and make some elements ,that dont hold on the scren, like dropdown